# Symfony2 simple nonsymfony php file how to route?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I have a simple php file say just

```
<?php echo "Hello World"?>
```

Where should I put the file and how should I write the config, so that I can create a route to this file when I go to http://domainname/externalphp.php

I'd assume it does not have to involve any controller or anything like that, since this is external php.

Comment: If you put it in `web/somefolder/phpscript.php`, you can navigate to it directly - but this wouldn't use custom pretty routes (which appears to be critical to the question).

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change your apache/nginx vhost configuration for that.

Your current configuration rewrites requests to your web/ folder to go through the app.php (or app_dev.php in the dev environment) file.
You will need to add a special case for '/externalphp.php' to avoid this rewriting.

Comment: so, I have put the file on web directory. if I have basic html file, the page is shown in the browser, but if it's php file, it will get downloaded. How to fix this?

Comment: The answer to this question is the same as my reply above. First, what web server do you use? Apache? Nginx?